# Map Network drive to Azure Blob Storage using SAS

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

Azure [SAS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-dotnet-shared-access-signature-part-1/)

From what I have read you can put a SAS URI in the browser and bring up the file

You can also create a SAS with list and read permission to the container. In .NET I follow how to use that.

Can you map that SAS list and read as a network drive in Windows Explorer and see the file?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Map Network drive to Azure Blob Storage using SAS.

Azure Blob Storage doesn't support to be mapped as a network drive in the Windows Explorer currently.  If we want to mange Azure blob we can use [Microsoft Azure Storage Explorer](http://storageexplorer.com/). for more information refer [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vs-azure-tools-storage-explorer-blobs).

If we want to map a network drive in Windows Explorer, please use Azure file storage, more detail about Azure file storage please refer to [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-files#mount-the-file-share).

```
net use <drive-letter>: \\<storage-account-name>.file.core.windows.net\<share-name> /u:AZURE\<storage-account-name> <storage-account-key>
example :
net use z: \\samples.file.core.windows.net\logs /u:AZURE\samples <storage-account-key>
```

Note:

- Install a version of Windows which supports SMB 3.0. Windows will
  leverage SMB 3.0 encryption to securely transfer data between your
  on-premises client and the Azure file share in the cloud.
- Open Internet access for port 445 (TCP Outbound) in your local
  network, as is required by the SMB protocol.

Comment: Thats what I thought too but wanted to check if anyone knew about a tool to do this through SAS. Thanks for the detailed info.